# Method gerResultPow not working in calculator

Tags: java, android

I am building my calculator app right now.Everything is working fine, except pow method.

When I click 8+5, and then pow method, I get these:

```
calculatorat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.atlant.calculator.calculatorat, PID: 28984
                                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "7+7"
                                                                                    at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
                                                                                    at java.lang.StringToReal.initialParse(StringToReal.java:164)
                                                                                    at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:282)
                                                                                    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
                                                                                    at com.atlant.calculator.calculatorat.Calculator.getResultPow(Calculator.java:178)
                                                                                    at com.atlant.calculator.calculatorat.Calculator.onClickPow(Calculator.java:205)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

There is no problem about comparing Strings, I know I can compare them with .equals!.Problem is with my 3rd case of getResultPow.

I only get error from 3.rd case in getResultPow (When I try to sum two numbers and then click POW).POW is working fine for 1.st and 2.nd case (number entered and then clicked POW).

Here is my github repo: [https://github.com/adnxy/CalculatorAt][1]

Anybody suggestions?

**Bellow is my onClickPow:**

```
public void onClickPow(View v) {
    if (display == "") return;
    if (!getResultPow()) return;
    {
        _screen.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    }

}
```

**My getResultPow method with three cases: 1.st and 2.nd case are working ,but when I click third I get error.**

```
//1.st case ,all empty, working fine
    if (display == "" && currentOperator == "" && result == "") return false;

    //2.nd case, entered number+pow, working fine
    if (currentOperator == "" && result == "" )
    if (display != "") {
        result = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(display) * Double.parseDouble(display));
    }

//3rd. case, two numbers entered and pow clicked, exception
if (result == "")
if (display != "" && currentOperator != "") {
    result = String.valueOf(String.valueOf(result)+Double.parseDouble(display) * Double.parseDouble(display));
    return true;
}


  [1]: https://github.com/adnxy/CalculatorAt
```

Comment: The onClickPow() doesn't look right here
if (!getResultPow()) return;
{
        _screen.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    }
Why do you return and then open brackets?

Comment: @apkisbossin what is wrong? It is working fine with 1st and 2nd case

Comment: My first suggestion would be to include the rest of the stack trace in your question, so we can see what the cause of the exception is that you're getting.

Comment: @azurefrog There it is:)thanks

Comment: So, the root cause exception is pretty clear, `7+7` is not a legal floating point number.  You need to turn each 7 into a number and then add them.

Comment: @azurefrog How can I fix that? Thank you bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the third error. Your're trying to convert to double the String `7+7`. Try to write:

```
Double pow = Double.parseDouble(display) * Double.parseDouble(display);
result = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(Double.parseDouble(result)+pow));
```

Comment: The same? Or is it different? Try to read the logcat output and see what would be wrong.

Comment: This is  if 3rd case right now:                                                            (display != "" && currentOperator != "" && result == "") {
            Log.d("Trecu slucaj radi","radi3");
            Log.d("Display prikaz broj3",display);
            Double pow = Double.parseDouble(display) * Double.parseDouble(display);
            result = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(result)+pow)));
            Log.d("Rezultat treceg slucaja3",result);

            return true;
        }

Comment: and same log output

Comment: I am aware, how your code looks, please read the logcat output.
And fix the `result = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(result)+pow)‌​));` to `result = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(Double.parseDouble(result)+pow));`